# C# : What Will Be The Greatest? Multiple Task or Single for One Job?

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, multitasking

I have this code:

```
public async virtual void Start(IPAddress ip, int port)
    {
        //Start listening proccess
        Listener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
        Listener.Start();
        IsListening = true;
        await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (IsListening)
                {
                    if (Listener.Pending())
                    {
                        TcpClient client = await Listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                        SkyfilterClient sklient = new SkyfilterClient(client);
                        byte command = sklient.Reader.ReadByte();
                        if (command == (byte) SkyfilterCommand.Authenticate)
                        {
                            sklient = await Authenticate(sklient);
                        }
                        else if(command == (byte)SkyfilterCommand.Register)
                        {
                            sklient = await Register(sklient);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Code at the Program.cs, main method

```
new SkyfilterCoreLib.Network.SkyfilterServer().Start(IPAddress.Loopback, 7812);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Is it best if i have async lambda ? Or i just only use one task and let the listener use `Listener.AcceptTcpClient` only ? Which one have the best performance?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you're creating a task at all. You're awaiting the completion of that task anyway, so why not just use:

```
Listener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
Listener.Start();
IsListening = true;
while (IsListening)
{
    if (Listener.Pending())
    {
        var client = await Listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        // I assume you want to do something with the client now...
    }
}
```

In this case it wouldn't make much difference if you made this bit synchronous - it really depends on whether you want the business of listening an asynchronous operation in itself.

I think the bigger question is what you're going to do with the client once you've accepted it. You may well want to use another asynchronous method to handle the client *but not await the result*:

```
List<Task> ongoingTasks = new List<Task>();
...
var client = await Listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
ongoingTasks.Add(HandleClientAsync(client));
```

Then when you want to shut down, you can wait for all the ongoing tasks to complete (possibly with a timeout) before you let the process die.

Comment: @AdityaHeartly: It depends on what exactly you mean by "block" and what the rest of your code does - but it won't do anything worse than your previous code, which awaited the newly created task. How well do you understand what await does?

Comment: i only used await for a few days ago. When i do the loop outside a task, its block my program for listening an input (Console). I need my program to be responsive even when it processing something. Should i await the `Task.Run` and dont wait for `AcceptTcpClient`, or should i await the `Task.Run` and let `AcceptTcpClient` run synchronously?

Comment: @AdityaHeartly: Sorry, it's not really clear what you mean by any of that. You'd have to show significantly more code to explain what you mean. But if you're able to listen for input asynchronously as well, you should be able to handle all of this reasonably simply.

Comment: What Im asking is, is it considered good if I have await a task that have await expression in inside of it? I'll edit my code

Comment: @AdityaHeartly: In itself that's okay - but it's pointless if you just start the task and await it, when you know the task itself won't consume much time. It's like starting a new thread and then calling `Join` on it. It would make sense if you were doing CPU-intensive work in the other thread, and wanted to avoid blocking the UI thread or something like that - but it's not the case here.

Comment: So, which one should i remove? The one with while loop on it took times for a hours, or maybe days (Its a server, it will run forever). So, should i delete the one that await the `AcceptTcpClient`?

After I accept it, i will use it for database access. After that, i will gave the client to manager that manage the client for messaging, connectivity checking, and much more for a long time. Should i keep it?

Comment: @AdityaHeartly: Which *what* should you remove? Sorry, I really don't think we've got enough context to help you at the moment.